# Ansible Inventory Link

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible and trying to learn the basics. But apparently I already fail with setting up the inventory file.

For the setup:
1) Installed ansible via homebrew
2) as no ansible.cfg was created, I created one manually in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
inventory = /etc/ansible/hosts/;
```

3) a hosts file was also not there, so I created the same in /etc/ansible/hosts

**hosts**

```
Test1
Test2
```

When I run `ansible all --list-hosts` I get the error:

```
[WARNING]: Unable to parse /etc/ansible/hosts; as an inventory source
```

As the path is correctly reflected in the error, I at least assume, the cfg is read correctly. But still the target file hosts is not being recognized. I tried differennt paths. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `/;` from the end of the inventory-line in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`:

```
cat /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
[defaults]
inventory = /etc/ansible/hosts
```

you could use `ansible -i /etc/ansible/hosts` to tell ansible use this inventory file.

Comment: I tried that, but still the same error. I want to keep the inventory definition implicit

Comment: did you realy remove the slash and the semikolon?